# How to apply functions on deep nested lists in a clean way?

Tags: r, list

In nested lists like this one

```
l <- list(list(list(111, 112, 113), list(121, 122, 123)),
          list(list(211, 212, 213), list(221, 222, 223)))

> str(l )
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : num 111
  .. ..$ : num 112
  .. ..$ : num 113
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : num 121
  .. ..$ : num 122
  .. ..$ : num 123
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : num 211
  .. ..$ : num 212
  .. ..$ : num 213
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ : num 221
  .. ..$ : num 222
  .. ..$ : num 223
```

we can apply a function, e.g. `length()` on the first level by this

```
lapply(l, length)
```

But when applying functions on deeper nested levels the size of my code increases exponentially...

```
# apply length() on second level
lapply(l, function(x)
  lapply(x, function(y) length(y)))

# square every list element of second level
lapply(l, function(x) 
  lapply(x, function(y) 
    lapply(y, function(z) z^2)))
```

Or, to change elements that appear at certain positions in lists of lower levels (i.e. modifications of LHS), I have no better idea than do a for loop.

```
# subtract 1 from first element of each second level list
for(i in sequence(length(l))) {
  l[[i]][[1]][[1]] <- l[[i]][[1]][[1]] - 1
  l[[i]][[2]][[1]] <- l[[i]][[2]][[1]] - 1
}
```

Have I missed something? Are there any cleaner ***base R*** solutions?

Comment: `rapply(l, myFunction, how="list")`?

Comment: @Cath This is a great hint, thanks!

Comment: Not what you are asking but `lengths()` can be used instead of `lapply(l, length)`.

Comment: ALso `l[[i]][[1]][[1]]` can be simplified to: `l[[c(i, 1, 1)]] `.

Comment: @snoram Also valuable knowledge, thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience lists are not easy to master (hope to get there one day). I don't know of a magic bullet but here are some *marginal* steps you can do simplify your current code:

```
lengths(l)
# instead of
lapply(l, length)


lapply(l, lengths)
# instead of
lapply(l, function(x)
  lapply(x, function(y) length(y)))


rapply(l, function(x) x^2, how="list") # credit to Cath
# instead of
lapply(l, function(x) 
  lapply(x, function(y) 
    lapply(y, function(z) z^2)))


for (i in seq_along(l)) {
  l[[i]] <- lapply(l[[i]], function(x) {x[[1]] <- x[[1]] - 1; x})
}
# Instead of 
for(i in sequence(length(l))) {
  l[[i]][[1]][[1]] <- l[[i]][[1]][[1]] - 1
  l[[i]][[2]][[1]] <- l[[i]][[2]][[1]] - 1
}
```